# Where are my git branches?

Tags: git

I was working on my work computer the other day and set up a new branch in github. I made a local and remote branch.

Today I am working on my laptop at home and I don't see my branch that I made when I run "git branch".

How do I get access to this branch?

Comment: did you `pull` your repo?

Comment: what does that mean? Do I run "git pull <branch name>?"

Comment: You haven't run `git fetch` on your laptop since creating the remote branch.

Comment: run `git pull --all` and see if your remote branch isn't there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you have this branch in your local repository, you can use `git checkout <branchname>` to checkout a branch

If this branch is on the github repository but not in your local repository, you may want to `git remote update` before `git checkout <branchname>` and `git pull` to fetch changes

Comment: but when I run "git branch" I don't see my branch listed. Doesn't that mean it's not there?

Comment: probably not in your local repository.  I just revised my answer with more info

Comment: thanks michael. So I just ran "git remote update" and now when I run "git branch -a" I see my branch there but it's in a different colour than the other branches. It's red. What does this mean? WHen I run "git branch" i don't see my branch...

Comment: ah, you probably see it under `remotes/origin/<branchname>` ... try `git checkout origin/<branchname>`

Comment: um, I did what you said and got this message. What does this mean? 

ou are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 2e6e49a... added changes to the rates page

Comment: it means that you're only really "looking" at the branch... I can't explain it better than the text already has.  What you want to do instead is `git checkout origin/<branchname> -b <branchname>`

Comment: YESSS!! thank you so much Michael. I'm not sure exactly what I just did...lol why did I have to do that last command? Just for my understanding I'd like to know what just happened. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me btw. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Your branch was created on the server, but you didn't have a version of that branch in your local working tree.  You might have been able to just run `git checkout <branchname>` from the start and it might have created the new branch for you automatically tracking origin.

Comment: gotcha. so even if I didn't see my branch when I ran "git branch" if I had run "git checkout <branch name>" from the beginning it would done all the above automatically?

Comment: first `git remote update` then `git checkout <branchname>`

Answer (score 2):

What seems to have happened here, is that your local cache of the remote state is outdated. Before you can access these new branches you will need to refresh your local copy of the repository's state.

You can do this with:

1. `git remote update` (see the [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33674155/1803692) by [Michael Ira Krufky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535550/michael-ira-krufky))
2. `git fetch [remotename]`

Additionally when you run `git pull` this automatically includes a `git fetch` so that would also update your local copy

Answer (score 1):

try `git branch -a` to show all the branches.

Comment: thanks, I did that but it still doesn't show the branch I made. It shows other branches though...

Comment: can you see the branch on github or something else? I mean to check if it was ever created.

Comment: yes it's definitely there. when I run git branch -a now I see my branch but it's in a different colour than the other branches

Comment: try `git checkout origin/<branchname>` or `git pull -all`